# Latex bibliography with mixed entry styles

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I'm writing a PhD thesis with

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

I would like to highlight the papers written by me by using, only for them, a different bibliography style as in the following example:

> [1] Reference 1
>
> [2] Reference 2
>
> (...)
>
> [Atz13] My reference 1
>
> [Atz14] My reference 2
>
> (...)

Is this possible to implement?

Comment: Can you add a complete (minimal) compilable example to play with?

Answer (score 1):

Since you edit your dissertation only once in its final format, you can resort to the inelegant solution of compiling your bibliography with `bibtex`, but editing the `bbl` file before the *final* compilations of the document.

For your example above, you would simply add the desired labels [Atz13] and [Atz14] in the `\bibitem` declarations of your own papers. Then comment out calls to `bibtex`, and insert the concents of your `bbl` file instead. Compile twice.

Comment: Maybe copy the contents of `yourfile.bbl` into the master document, since there is no reason to keep it in a seperate file when this solution is used.

Comment: True, I edited answer.

Comment: Looks like the sanest solution for an essentially one-shot job.